# How to specify $HOME folder in sublime-build file?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I am using a custom build system in Sublime Text 3 for a C++ project. One of the lines looks like

```
"-I${HOME}/my_file/include"
```

The problem is that `${HOME}` does not expand to the actual `/home/user_x`, but expands to an empty string `''`. I cannot find any way of specifying the `HOME` folder elegantly, without the need to write the actual path. Is there a way of doing this? I.e., to expand the UNIX `$HOME` variable to the actual location of the home folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're running afoul of here is that the `cmd`, `shell_cmd` and `working_dir` arguments are [all subject to variable expansion](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#variables) in build systems.

What's not outlined there is that anything of this format is treated as a variable when the expansion happens, and unknown variables are expanded to an empty string (i.e. no value).

As such, Sublime sees your `${HOME}` and tries to expand it, which unhelpfully removes it's value from the string.

The easiest and least invasive way around this is to quote the `$` character in the variable expansion so that Sublime will ignore it and pass it through, where the shell can expand it as appropriate:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "echo Home is \\${HOME}"
}
```

or

```json
{
    "cmd": "echo Home is \\${HOME}",
    "shell": true
}
```

Note that as seen in these examples you need to use either `shell_cmd` with a complete command string or `cmd` with a command string in combination with `shell` being set to `true` in order for this to work.

Note also that the quoting appears to be doubled because the build file is JSON. So when the build is loaded, `\\${HOME}` is internally seen by Sublime as `\${HOME}` (i.e. it "eats" the first level of quoting), and the final quoting causes Sublime to treat the `$` as a literal and not special so that it will be passed to the shell, which expands it itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your commands to a shell script and running the script from Sublime. I'm not sure if Sublime supports this feature, but shell script should find and expand $HOME and any other variables.

Comment: Indeed, the shell expands it correctly, I was wondering if Sublime can do this as well. Seems like a modest feature to support :)

Comment: As per http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html, you could also try setting `shell` to `true`. Might work.